# numref table is undefined label

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I use numref for table.  When I  use `make  latexpdf`, I get a warning `undefined label: tab-wave-breaking`.

I have two tables, and I get the error in first table every time, also when I change these tables' order.

```
label as follows: Table :numref:`tab-wave-breaking`.

.. _tab-wave-breaking:

.. table:: Different wave breaking formulations implemented

    +-----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | Wave breaking formula       | Type of waves   | keyword          |
    +=============================+=================+==================+
    | Roelvink (1993a)            | Instationary    | roelvink1        |
    +-----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | Roelvink (1993a) extended   | Instationary    | roelvink2        |
    +-----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | Daly et al. (2010)          | Instationary    | roelvink_daly    |
    +-----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | Baldock et al. (1998)       | Stationary      | baldock          |
    +-----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | Janssen & Battjes (2007)    | Stationary      | janssen          |
    +-----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+


用户或进程可能具有的特权如 :numref:`tab-wave-breaking1` 所示。

.. _tab-wave-breaking1:

.. table:: 用户或进程特权列表 

   +------+----------------------+----------------------------+
   | 序号 |         名称         |            含义            |
   +======+======================+============================+
   | 1    | CAP_CHOWN            | 本权能超越改变文件所有关系 |
   |      |                      | 和组所有关系。             |
   +------+----------------------+----------------------------+
```

`make latexpdf`

```
xxxxxxxx/07_安全管理工具.rst:369: WARNING: undefined label: tab-wave-breaking
```

and the conf.py is:

```
latex_documents = [
    ('index', 'xx.tex', 'xx',
     'xx', 'manual', True),
]

numfig=True
#numfig_format=True
numfig_secnum_depth=1
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. It works fine for me.

Comment: i preport a bug in github https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9638

Comment: thank you , what is your sphix's Version

Comment: Sphinx version 4.2.0.

Comment: Turned out to be a docutils bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/bugs/425/.